# Does google-play-service-lib revision 23 compatible with ATInternet 1.4.000?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Currently ATInternet tracking is used in my project with ATInternet jar version is 1.4.000 and recently I have updated Google Play Service with revision 23 and refering it in project. I am getting runtime exception as follows:

03-25 11:26:15.095: E/AndroidRuntime(19899): java.lang.VerifyError: com/atinternet/tag/ATPhoneInformation

03-25 11:26:15.095: E/AndroidRuntime(19899):    at com.atinternet.tag.ATTag.(ATTag.java:290)

03-25 11:26:15.095: E/AndroidRuntime(19899):    at com.atinternet.tag.ATTag.init(ATTag.java:409)

Comment: While it would certainly be nice to see more information, note that the code in the question **appears to come from a compiled jar** - ie, **the poster probably doesn't have access to the source to post it**.  Sometimes, one has to debug problems that occur not because of the code being written, but because of oddities with the libraries used or the device being targeted.

Comment: One step that could be productive though would be to use something like apktool to see if you can figure out what the offending line is trying to do.  You could also check for newer versions or known issues with the library.

Comment: Yes its regarding library, but I have tried using following tag into my project's manifest                                                                            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />              then too at runtime verify error exception is thrown, so I thought there is possibility that ATInternet 1.4.000 might not be compatible with Google Play Service revision 23.